# Wrong keyboard layout Ubuntu 22 Spanish

Tags: keyboard-layout

I tried all combinations, even copying the configuration from another laptop which is the same, I don't know what's wrong with this machine. It's a Thinkpad T15 Gen2, I'm attaching a screenshot of the actual keyboard:
[image]

I tried all Spanish combinations. The layout now shows this:
[image]

I even tried setting a generic keyboard doing sudo dpgb-reconfigure keyboard-configuration.

What's the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Ubuntu 22 would be Ubuntu Core 22. If it is not please edit the question with the correct version info.

Comment: Is that Thinkpad keybord really designed for Spanish speaking users?

Comment: @David I don't know if it's "core" or not. What's the difference? And how do I check?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes it is, as long as it has the ñ, it's perfect for Spanish, why do you ask?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the ñ. It looks like there is no XKB layout which matches your physical keyboard exactly. So you can either live with the differences or create a modified personal keyboard layout.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If I were you, I just edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es`. Please don't forget copy file and keep the original.